# Why does the behavior of the patch library change depending on how values are imported?

Tags: python, magicmock

The `patch` function from the `mock` library is sensitive to how things are imported. Is there a deep reason why I can't just use the fully qualified name where the function was originally defined regardless of how it is imported in other modules?

using a "module import" works fine

patch_example.py:

```
# WORKS!
from mock import patch
import inner

def outer(x):
    return ("outer", inner.inner(x))

@patch("inner.inner")
def test(mock_inner):
    mock_inner.return_value = "MOCK"
    assert outer(1) == ("outer", "MOCK")
    return "SUCCESS"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print test()
```

inner.py:

```
def inner(x):
    return ("inner.inner", x)
```

Running `python patch_example.py` just outputs success.

However, changing the import can have pretty dramatic consequences

Using a module alias still works

```
# WORKS!
from mock import patch
import inner as inner2

def outer(x):
    return ("outer", inner2.inner(x))

@patch("inner.inner")
def test(mock_inner):
    mock_inner.return_value = "MOCK"
    assert outer(1) == ("outer", "MOCK")
    return "SUCCESS"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print test()
```

directly importing the symbol, however, requires you to change the fully qualified name.

direct import, `inner.inner` as fully qualified name.

```
# FAILS!
from mock import patch
from inner import inner

def outer(x):
    return ("outer", inner(x))

@patch("inner.inner")
def test(mock_inner):
    mock_inner.return_value = "MOCK"
    assert outer(1) == ("outer", "MOCK")
    return "SUCCESS"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print test()
```

produces

```
% python patch_example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "patch_example.py", line 14, in <module>
    print test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "patch_example.py", line 10, in test
    assert outer(1) == ("outer", "MOCK")
AssertionError
```

If I update the fully qualified path to `patch_example.inner`, the patch still fails.

```
# FAILS!
from mock import patch
from inner import inner

def outer(x):
    return ("outer", inner(x))

@patch("patch_example.inner")
def test(mock_inner):
    mock_inner.return_value = "MOCK"
    assert outer(1) == ("outer", "MOCK")
    return "SUCCESS"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print test()

% python patch_example.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "patch_example.py", line 14, in <module>
    print test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "patch_example.py", line 10, in test
    assert outer(1) == ("outer", "MOCK")
AssertionError
```

using `__main__.inner` as my fully qualified name patches the right thing though.

```
# WORKS!
from mock import patch
from inner import inner

def outer(x):
    return ("outer", inner(x))

@patch("__main__.inner")
def test(mock_inner):
    mock_inner.return_value = "MOCK"
    assert outer(1) == ("outer", "MOCK")
    return "SUCCESS"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print test()
```

prints "SUCCESS"

So, why can't I patch the value of inner when it's imported as `from inner import inner` using either the fully qualified name of the original symbol `inner.inner` or the use the name of the main python module rather than `__name__`?

Tested with Python 2.7.12 on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once you directly import the symbol there is **no link whatsoever** between the binding you are using in the `__main__` module and the binding found in the `inner` module. So `patch`ing *the module* does **not** change the already imported symbols.

Importing a module using an alias doesn't matter because `patch` will lookup the `sys.modules` dictionary, which still keep track of the original name, so that's why this works (actually: when calling the mock the module is freshly imported, so it doesn't matter the name in which you imported it when calling `patch`)

In other words: you have to patch *both* bindings because they are effectively unrelated. There is no way for patch to know where all references to `inner.inner` ended up and patch them.

In this situation the second argument of `patch` might be useful to specify an existing mock object that can be shared to patch all bindings.